# Populate one value to another value when clicking on a checkbox

Tags: workflow

I am new to workflows.I have a requirement where I want to copy the Caller demographic fields to the patient fields when the agent checks the checkbox.

Comment: Are those fields on the same Object?

Comment: yes they are on the same object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a  workflow rule

[image]

set your rule criteria if your checkbox to true

Workflow Actions

Create a field update

[image]

now select field to update (i.e. patient )

[image]

in formula click on field button and add demographic field and click done

Comment: Thanks Ratan,if there are 4 fields of patient would I have to write seperately each workflow

Comment: yes @kunalgupta

Answer (score 0):

The fields you've mentioned either need to be on the same object, or a related object in order for this to be accomplished via a workflow.

Create a workflow rule on the object the checkbox is located on.

For the Evaluation Criteria:
Select "created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria"

For Rule Criteria:
Select the checkbox field, set the operator to EQUALS, and the value to TRUE.

On the Specify Workflow Actions Page, click Add Workflow Action - New Field Update. Select the patient field as the Field To Update.

On the Field Update Edit page, select Use a formula to set the new value.

In the formula editor, select insert field, and select the caller demographic field.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a Workflow Rule with Field Updates.  (Using non Lightning UI)

Click Setup
Under Build go to Create
Then Select Workflow & Approvals
Then Workflow Rules

Click New Rules
Select the Object they live on
Give it a Name and Description
Select for Evaluation Criteria of Created and any time its edited to subsequently meet criteria
Set the Rule Criteira to Field Checkbox Equals True

Click Save & Next
Click Add Workflow Action (You'll do this for every field update you'll want updated)
Select Field Update
Give it a Name and Description
Select the field you want to update
Click Next
Click on Use a Formula to set the new Value
Then click show Formula Editor
Click the Insert Field button and find the field you want to copy over
Click Save

Once active this should accomplish your needs.